# What is the best way to pass data from one View to another in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

What is the best way to pass data from one View to another in Xamarin using MVVM pattern?

Does passing in the constructor the best option even when data is large in the object?

What other pattern can we use for passing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in `Xamarin.Forms` there are many ways to do this (depending on how you have structured your app).

If the page is already open you can use *MessagingCenter* to send from one ViewModel or Page To the other while keeping a [decoupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) architecture

**Sender**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```

**Receiver**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
```

---

If you are creating the Page as apposed to a framework creating it for you, you can just pass in the data through the Page Constructor,

**New Page Constructor**

```
public MyPage(string someText)
{
}
```

**Sender**

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyPage(<YourTextHere>)));
```

**or via a Property**

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyPage() { SomneProperty = "blach" ));
```

---

**Additional Resource**

[MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Comment: Does the messaging center have to send a string? Can it send a variable that represents a string?